# Can't add products to WooCommerce cart. Strange jQuery error that I don't understand

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently a client site that I helped set up on WooCommerce has started having upload issues. I reinstalled Wordpress and it allowed her to upload images for a few hours before presenting another problem.

Now customers are calling her saying that they can't add products to their cart. They are variable products and the prices are all set correctly. Every help thread I've found says to look for Javascript errors, which I did with the help of Chrome. Here's the only error that's showing in the console:

```
jquery-2.2.3.min.js?ver=2.2.3:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://galeria.przedszkole.lebork.pl/?The-Psychodynamics-of-Race--Vicious-and-Benign-Spirals.pdf
```

I have no idea how to find or fix this issue. I installed a plugin that updates Jquery hoping that it would just overwrite any errors but that didn't help. Here's one of the products where the error occurs: http://agirlstreasures.net/?product=dusty-pink-ruffle-lace-vest#
Any help would be amazing!

UPDATE - Problem Fixed!

Thanks for the help. I was able to fix it. There was a rogue php file that was injecting all sort of crap in my site. I installed a plugin called WordFence to scan for any recent changes to files and it showed me these 3 issues:

---

- [Apr 27 16:22:57] Adding issue: File appears to be malicious: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/simplify-commerce/assets/images/cards.php
- [Apr 27 16:22:57] Adding issue: File appears to be malicious:
  wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shipping/flat-rate/includes/settings-flat-rate.php.php
- [Apr 27 16:22:57] Adding issue: File appears to be malicious:
  wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/external.php.php

I deleted those 3 files and changed all the passwords. Just thought I'd drop back in case anyone else came across a similar problem. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Try to switch to a new theme to rule out theme compatibility issues

Comment: I switched themes with no changes. Even with Twenty15 active there are these strange URLS injected everywhere. I even installed a fresh version of the theme but the code isn't in the theme files.

Comment: Site is compromised, you'll need to get the site cleaned.

Comment: Reinstall wordpress? What should I do to clean the site.

Comment: Reinstalling WordPress only won't help. If you aren't sure of what to do, get an expert's help.